# Creating a list of physical locations in intranet

Tags: ping, port, switch

For the intranet of my workplace, I have inventory data including Netname and location within building of our PCs. I would like to create a list of network wall sockets with location in building, so that if a PC is moved I can find it.

If I ping a PC by Netname, I think I should be able to get some info about the network switch port or something, which will uniquely identify what network wall plate it is plugged in to.

How can I generate the list of network info using a list of Netnames with known physical locations? I am using Windows and ASP.Net.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I ping a PC by Netname, I think I should be able to get some info about the network switch port or something, which will uniquely identify what network wall plate it is plugged in to.

Only if your switch reports that information. There are a few options:

1. You connect to the switch's management interface and search its "MAC address table" for the computer's MAC address, which will show you the switch port that it's connected to.

   Then look up that switch port in your docs to find out which physical wall-jack it goes to.

   Automating this will be annoying; the MAC address lookup could be done via SNMP or Netmiko or Expect (and the port-to-walljack mapping of course needs to be done manually).
2. Or, you enable LLDP (or the older CDP) through your switch's management interface, then you use an LLDP client on the computer to read the LLDP announcements from the switch, which will indicate the switch name and port number. (Windows doesn't have a good one, but Wireshark or another packet capture tool will do the job.)

   Automating this is usually even more annoying, though *possible*. I don't know of any good LLDP client for Windows PCs; if there were one, it could be run remotely on some target PC via `Invoke-Command` or `winrs`.

   (Some devices send their own LLDP announcements which the switch will collect; such devices will then be listed in the switch's management interface.)

In all cases you need the wall jacks to be connected to a managed switch. ("Web-managed" might not be enough, unfortunately. We have ended up with a lot of cheap switches that technically have web-based management but don't even show their MAC table anywhere.)

Comment: My 1 rep isn't enough to even upvote yet. I will have to look this over and try to understand it. Thank you.

Comment: Is there any kind of info I can get about the route taken to a PC that would be consistent? All I need is something that is always the same with a particular network wall socket, then I can make my own association table.

Comment: Nothing more than what I've already written, unfortunately. The answer is still the same – if the route is being taken through switches, then the switches are the only ones that know the route (it is *completely* invisible to the PCs or to the router), and so you unavoidably need "managed" switches that you can connect to and see the information. (Yeah, I'd love if switches had an universal "L2 traceroute" but that's an extremely rare feature, so LLDP or MAC-table is all you get.)

Answer (score 0):

I was given a spreadsheet that included MAC Address and switch and port data, among other things. I pulled that in to SQL and correlated with our Inventory data of PCs and Printers (which has MAC Address info) and generated a static SQL table of switch + port --> Building + Floor + Room number. Select INTO - yay!

So now at least the info is known, for locations that had something plugged in when the data was acquired. It is a workaround, but how often do we rearrange the wires in the wall?

Someday someone will create a usable method to query from a PC and get the switch and port being used, and then the Inventory can be self-verifying. It will warn if the map doesn't match the terrain, so to speak. We can hope.

Probably we will go to full wireless, once that is as secure as wired access, before that happens. But, it would still be good to be able to figure out exactly where a PC is...

Comment: There **already is** a method to query the PC for the switch/port... but, as already mentioned, it is only possible when the switch provides such information. If the switch doesn't do LLDP or CDP, then it's fundamentally impossible for the PC to know which of 24 completely identical ports it's on.

Comment: @u1686_grawity We have stuff like WMIC which provides all kinds of info that I have been able to use. Add it to that maybe? And, the ports are not identical: they go to different places in the building. Inquiring Admins want to know. Wouldn't self-validating Inventory be a good thing? I'm one simple query away from that. How about my static table workaround?